# I can't run zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

i am new to the kafka world,
i want to start zookeeper then when i type this

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

I got the following error

```
ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally  (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use

ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Then i tried `netstat -nlp|grep 2181`
 but there is no process running

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2181            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Some light please

Answer (score 11):

For this case,
You need to see if zookeeper is running or not

use below command

```
sudo lsof -i :2181
```

You will get

```
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java     1005 zookeeper   33u  IPv6  17209      0t0  TCP *:2181 (LISTEN)
java     1005 zookeeper   34u  IPv6 327225      0t0  TCP localhost:2181->localhost:43566 (ESTABLISHED)
java    22585      root   88u  IPv6 324552      0t0  TCP localhost:43566->localhost:2181 (ESTABLISHED)
```

like statement. Now kill the zookeeper to start again.

```
sudo kill -9 1005
```

Then use below to start zookeeper

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like zookeeper server is running.

try:

`bin/zkServer.sh stop` from the zookeeper directory to shut it down and then:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

from the `kafka` directory

That fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

There must be some stale process using the port 2181.I had the same issue.First I checked the status of the server:

```
/usr/share/zookeeper$ bin/zkServer.sh status
```

or

```
/usr/share/zookeeper$ echo status | nc 127.0.0.1 2181
```

Then, I tried to start kafka and it failed with the same error. I changed permission and run as sudo..it didn't work either.
Since i couldn't see any process using the port. I restarted my computer and it worked!!.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `zookeeper` is already running or not by using this command.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

Check if you get number of topics, if you get any that means Zookeeper was already running.
So verify whether Zookeeper is already running or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running command **bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties**

and getting error :

```
  ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
```

In that case in your virtual machine **port 2181** is already using by zookeeper.

so in kafka **zookeeper.properties** change the **clientPort** value to the port which is not in use like **5181**

Again run the command and Zookeeper will start working.

Answer (score 1):

First, stop the `Zookeeper` with the command below:

```
$ bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Then, start it again and you should be good to go:

```
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

May be another user is running the process. check using jps if any process with Quorum is running kill it and then try

Comment: @Pandey Thanks for your reply , i tried your suggestion but no process  with Quorum is running

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by doing following commands.

1. Go to kafka folder where you installed and type `sudo bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh`
2. `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`

I hope this helps. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe you can stop your hbase first.**

just like this follow..

```sh
[root@master kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0]# stop-hbase.sh 
stopping hbase................
localhost: stopping zookeeper.
[root@master kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0]# jps
2903 ResourceManager
60745 Worker
2586 NameNode
2762 SecondaryNameNode
93996 Jps
60653 Master
[root@master kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0]# bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
[2019-12-05 01:09:43,959] INFO Reading configuration from: config/zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2019-12-05 01:09:43,965] INFO autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2019-12-05 01:09:43,965] INFO autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2019-12-05 01:09:43,965] INFO Purge task is not scheduled. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2019-12-05 01:09:43,965] WARN Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,013] INFO Reading configuration from: config/zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,013] INFO Starting server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,023] INFO Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.8--1, built on 02/06/2016 03:18 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,023] INFO Server environment:host.name=master (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,023] INFO Server environment:java.version=1.8.0_171 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,023] INFO Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,023] INFO Server environment:java.home=/usr/local/soft/jdk1.8.0_171/jre (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,023] INFO Server environment:java.class.path=:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.5.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/connect-api-0.10.1.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/connect-file-0.10.1.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/connect-json-0.10.1.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-0.10.1.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/guava-18.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.22.2.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.22.2.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.22.2.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.2.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.2.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.22.2.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-4.9.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0-sources.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0-test-sources.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-0.10.1.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-0.10.1.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-0.10.1.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-0.10.1.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-0.10.1.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.10.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-4.9.0.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.11.8.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/zkclient-0.9.jar:/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.4.8.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,024] INFO Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,024] INFO Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,024] INFO Server environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,024] INFO Server environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,024] INFO Server environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,024] INFO Server environment:os.version=2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,024] INFO Server environment:user.name=root (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,024] INFO Server environment:user.home=/root (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,025] INFO Server environment:user.dir=/usr/local/soft/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,035] INFO tickTime set to 3000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,035] INFO minSessionTimeout set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,035] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-05 01:09:44,050] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I got it because zookeeper server is crashed by my laptop crash.
I got solved by the help from the below link.

[How to recover Zookeeper from java.io.EOFException after a server crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217654/how-to-recover-zookeeper-from-java-io-eofexception-after-a-server-crash)

I found the offending log file by opening one by one [Zookeper-data-dir]/zookeeper_0/version-2. And found a log file without head or any other thing. When I deleted it, I got my problem solved and my zookeeper server started running normally.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the ZooKeeper port 2181 is still in use, Please follow the below steps to address this issue:

Use the netstat command to find the process that is holding onto port 2181. Kill the process that is using the ZooKeeper port 2181:

```
$ netstat -antp | grep 2181
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2181            0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN      28016/java <defunct>
$ kill -9 28016
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the kafka process solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is existing zookeeper running, how should I remove this. And than stop the zookeeper

> bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
> test

Answer (score 0):

Many mentioned the process for linux versions.

In case if we want to identify the same for windows, we can identify with below

From PowerShell, finding the port listening to 2181

```
PS C:\Users\<username>> netstat -ano | findstr 2181
  TCP    [::1]:2181             [::]:0                 LISTENING       4564
```

**Option #1**: kill that process id using task kill

```
PS C:\Users\vishnus> taskkill /F /PID 4564
```

In case this option doesn't work and failing

> ERROR: The process with PID 4564 could not be terminated.
> Reason: Access is denied.

**Option #2**

Go to "Task Manager" --> Services tab, check for PID column and go to that process and right click and mark it as stop. then it will get stopped.

By this time, the earlier instance is killed, so you can start the zookeeper

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and then I debug step by step and find the solution as follows:

1. stop the zookeeper:
   `/opt/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh`

   Then I check whether the zookeeper process has indeed been stopped:
   `ps aux | grep zookeeper`
   If the zookeeper has been stopped, then no zookeeper process should be displayed.  You can also check the zookeeper process via port number or java process. If your port number for zookeeper is the default 2181, you can check which process is listening to this port by running `sudo lsof -i :2181`. You can also check the all the java processs and find the corresponding zookeeper process by running `sudo ps -fC java`

   If the zookeeper has not been stopped, run `sudo kill -9 zookeeper_process_id` to kill it.

After this, we are sure that zookeeper have indeed been stopped. If we run `jps`, the `QuorumPeerMain` will not be shown.

2. After this, we can restart the zookeeper,

   /opt/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /opt/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/config/zookeeper.properties

Answer (score 0):

For windows user: below step will stop the zookeeper

step1 : ***netstat -ano | findstr :***

NOTE: port number can be replaced by the port where zookeeper is runing
[image]

Step2: Now from image , the circled one is PID so copy that and put it in below command

***taskkill /PID <PIDNO/F***
[image]