# How to recover Zookeeper from java.io.EOFException after a server crash?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

How to recover from the following error that started happening after a server crash? 
Zookeeper won’t start and the following message is showing repeatedly on the log.

```
2017-05-27 01:02:08,072 [myid:] - INFO [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,072 [myid:] - INFO [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,072 [myid:] - INFO [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA> 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,072 [myid:] - INFO [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.name=Linux 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,072 [myid:] - INFO [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.arch=amd64 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,073 [myid:] - INFO [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.version=3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,073 [myid:] - INFO [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.name=zookeeper 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,073 [myid:] - INFO [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.home=/opt/zookeeper 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,073 [myid:] - INFO [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.dir=/ 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,074 [myid:] - INFO [main:ZooKeeperServer@829] - tickTime set to 2000 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,074 [myid:] - INFO [main:ZooKeeperServer@838] - minSessionTimeout set to -1 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,074 [myid:] - INFO [main:ZooKeeperServer@847] - maxSessionTimeout set to -1 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,080 [myid:] - INFO [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@89] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,385 [myid:] - ERROR [main:Util@239] - Last transaction was partial. 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,400 [myid:] - ERROR [main:Util@239] - Last transaction was partial. 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,403 [myid:] - ERROR [main:Util@239] - Last transaction was partial. 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,403 [myid:] - ERROR [main:Util@239] - Last transaction was partial. 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,404 [myid:] - ERROR [main:Util@239] - Last transaction was partial. 
2017-05-27 01:02:08,404 [myid:] - ERROR [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@64] - Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally 
java.io.EOFException 
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392) 
at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readInt(BinaryInputArchive.java:63) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileHeader.deserialize(FileHeader.java:64) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.inStreamCreated(FileTxnLog.java:585) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.createInputArchive(FileTxnLog.java:604) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.goToNextLog(FileTxnLog.java:570) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.next(FileTxnLog.java:652) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:166) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.loadDataBase(ZKDatabase.java:223) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.loadData(ZooKeeperServer.java:283) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.startdata(ZooKeeperServer.java:410) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.startup(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:118) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:119) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:87) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:53) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:116) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
```

thanks 
IPVP

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you have encountered a known Apache ZooKeeper bug.  There are a few different Apache JIRA issues related to this: [ZOOKEEPER-1621](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1621) and [ZOOKEEPER-2332](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2332).  See the comments in those issues if you're interested in root cause analysis and some potential proposed fixes.

Unfortunately, there is no Apache ZooKeeper release that contains a fix for the bug at this time.  There are a few potential workarounds that you could try:

1. Create your own local build of ZooKeeper with one of the patches attached to the linked JIRA issues applied.  Please be advised that these patches have not yet been accepted by the ZooKeeper community, so use at your own risk.
2. Delete the offending log file.  The root cause of the problem is that a log file from a prior run of ZooKeeper was written with an incomplete header.  Since the header is at the start of the file, and the header itself is incomplete, we can assume that there is no transaction data in the log file after that point.  Therefore, it should be safe to delete without causing any data loss.
3. If it's easier, you might consider just reformatting this ZooKeeper cluster.  This may be an appropriate solution if all of the data in your ZooKeeper installation is ephemeral and doesn't require long-term persistence.

Answer (score 44):

The solution for me was to find the 0 length log file in /hadoop/zookeeper/version-2 (or whichever place your dataDir is) and delete it. 
Start ZooKeeper afterwards.

Comment: When I got this message the partition containing my data directory was full, so I had to give that some more space too.

Comment: This worked for me partially. After removing that file I got to see the actual error which was ```java.io.IOException: No space left on device``` as stated by @GordonGustafson

Answer (score 26):

The solution for me was to find the **last**  log file (which had 0 byte length)

You will find this inside the `version-2` directory

```
ls -l -r --sort=time

-rw-r--r-- 1 chris chris  67108880 Jan 24 10:37 log.23c6a70
-rw-r--r-- 1 chris chris         0 Jan 24 10:37 log.23d3fb4
```

I've tried first to delete the snapshot and the last 2 logfiles which is also working but then you would have version which is "a bit" older.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 chris chris  3685904 Jan 24 00:56 snapshot.23c6a6e
```

Maybe you have to delete the last snapshot file and the last logfile together and the 0 length logfile to be safe.

btw. Logfile and snapshot have the same HEX pattern which have to match

log.**23c6a**70

snapshot.**23c6a**6e

They have to match and be consistent and you should have this problem fixed.